# Java Object. Где реализация методов?

Tags: java

Добрый день. Начинаю изучать яву.
Захожу в исходники обджекта http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html
Класс не абстрактный, при этом есть такие методы 
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
где скрывается код этих функций? Где асемблерный или си код?

Comment: Ключевое слово `native` означает что исходники не на Java, а на C/C++

Comment: > не на Java, а на C/C++

@Barmaley, скажем так, "не на Java, а на другом языке"

Answer (score 7):

В исходниках JDK, конечно.

*src\share\native\java\lang\Object.c:*

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"hashCode",    "()I",                    (void *)&JVM_IHashCode},
    {"wait",        "(J)V",                   (void *)&JVM_MonitorWait},
    {"notify",      "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotify},
    {"notifyAll",   "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotifyAll},
    {"clone",       "()Ljava/lang/Object;",   (void *)&JVM_Clone},
};
```

Соответственно объявления из 
*src\share\javavm\export\jvm.h*:

```
/*
 * java.lang.Object
 */

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JVM_IHashCode(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
JVM_MonitorWait(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong ms);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
JVM_MonitorNotify(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
JVM_MonitorNotifyAll(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
JVM_Clone(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
```

Что в свою очередь отсылает нас к исходникам JVM. Ну а JVM, как понимаете, бывают разные с разными реализациями.

PS. Фрагменты кода взяты из сырцов OpenJDK.